# Android Studio Checkout From Version Control-Bitbucket

Tags: android, controls, bitbucket, version, vcs-checkout

My friend wanted to join my repository in android studio when he clicks on check out from version control he at first was given the option to log in and then nothing. he has git installed and also the Bitbucket plugin from the website also. Just when he clicks on check out he gets a loading bar and nothing.

Comment: Tell him to try cloning the project manually in order to discard connection, path or access issues (i.e.: repository permissions).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but maybe this is the problem https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/issue/56/solved-plugin-does-not-work-well-with-idea

I had the same problem, apparently it's a problem with the BitBucket plugin. I used the plugin from Dmitry Cherkas and it worked. Here's the link https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector_IC-133.193.zip